# iOS BLE how to get 11,25 ms connection interval?

Tags: ios

I want to get a 11,25 connection interval on iOS. But how can I check what connection interval was selected? I have a device with an accelerometer and gyroscope. I sent a request to a device from iOS to set connection between 11,25 and 31,25. I need to receive updates every 11,25 ms for my code. Can I somehow make the iOS device pick the lowest?

I need to connect to 2 devices and capture accelerometer and gyroscope data from both devices with interval of 11,25 ms. This is done on Android. When I am trying to do the same things on iOS I receive accelerometer data from one device almost in 10 ms intervals but others intervals are around 100 ms or even more. How can I improve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it will help people to suggest changes that can produce the behaviour you need. Also I'm not very familair with iOS development, but it seems like you're asking two questions here. If they're very related that can be acceptable, but usually it's best to ask one clear question in a post. If you feel they're separate, you can ask a new question and even link back to here to reference that it's for the same project.

Comment: 1 question, well detailed, please. No "another question"... otherwise you wont get any valuable answer.